# Slide Down Animation with Jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, slidedown

I'm looking to have a slide down animation (popular on a lot of forms these days) with jquery.
I have text injecting into a div. The text is fetched from a database.

```
   success: function(text, textS, xhr){
    if(xhr.status){
     if (text == "") {
      $("#resultsDiv").html(" ");
     }
     else {
      $("#resultsDiv").html(text.replace(/\+/g,"<br/>"));
     }
    }
   },
```

What do you think is the best way to go about implementing an animation into this process?

Comment: finish all the process of data in a separate method and finally attach the results to resultsDiv and then simply do slidedown on resultsDiv.

Comment: if you we have implemented search suggest on www.art.com , go to search box and type flo or edu three letters. It will make a ajax call to the backend and show you the results. It uses slidedown and slideup. Let me know if you need any more details ,i can provide guide you how to implement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look [in the manual](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) would have shown you what to do:

```
if (text == "") {
    $("#resultsDiv").html(" ").slideUp();
} else {
    $("#resultsDiv").html(text.replace(/\+/g,"<br/>")).slideDown();
}
```